# Should OSGi fragments export packages contributed to their host?

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-fragment

I noticed a fragment I have uses a `Export-Package` directive for the package that is contributed to its host:

```
Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot
Export-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot.utils;version="1.0.1.felix"
-buildpath: osgi.core;version=4.3.0,\
    org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot;version=7.6.1.v20120215
-sources: false
Import-Package: !org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot.utils.internal,\
    *
```

This bundle contributes some extra classes into the org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot.utils package in the host.

Ideally I think I should strive to keep packages private where possible, but what about this case? None of the rest of my code requires `org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot.utils`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the OSGi core specification (6.0):

> A host bundle's class path is searched before a fragment's class path.

*"This bundle contributes a new org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot.utils with classes that override those of the host"*

Fragment bundles cannot override the classes of the host bundle (if that was what you meant).

If a package is not intended to use by other bundles, it should not be exported. The host bundle can see the classes and resources of its attached fragment bundle, but only if it does not have the same class or resource.

Comment: You're right, in this case the class contributed into the package is instantiated by the already-present code in the host (see http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty.osgi/jetty-osgi-boot/9.1.1.v20140108/org/eclipse/jetty/osgi/boot/utils/BundleFileLocatorHelper.java). I'll correct that. So it sounds like it is safe to be `Private-Package`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer of @balazs-zsoldos:

> Fragment bundles cannot override the classes of the host bundle

...is correct *in this specific case*, but it is not true in general. A more nuanced answer would be that fragments cannot override the host bundle's classes *unless the host bundle has been configured to allow it* (which in your case the `org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot` bundle is not).

The way you configure the host bundle to allow it is by using the `Bundle-ClassPath` header. Let's assume you have a host bundle `A` with an attached fragment `B`, and `A` has the following manifest entry:

`Bundle-ClassPath: contrib,.`

Suppose the bundle classloader is asked to look for class `pack.Z` in bundle `A`. The bundle classloader will search in the following order:

1. `A:contrib/pack/Z.class`
2. `B:contrib/pack/Z.class`
3. `A:pack/Z.class`
4. `B:pack/Z.class`

So you can see that if your `contrib` directory in `A` is empty or non-existent, then the bundle classloader will try and load `B:contrib/pack/Z.class` before it will try and load `A:pack/Z.class`. But as you can see, this is only possible if `A` was explicitly built to allow it.